# How can I open a dll file to see it's namespace?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, namespaces

I received a few dlls to replace some old ones that I had (I don't have the source of the dlls).
I added them to my project, and in the references they have a little yellow mark next to them:
 [image]

In the include line, it says that the namespace couldn't be found.

How can I check what is the namespace in the dll files?

Answer (score 0):

If they have a yellow mark there is a problem.
If they are from a project you created, add the project in the solution also.
Also, check for the path and the version of the framework.
If you solve the yellow mark, the problem with the namespace will be solved too.